# How can I get the "color" and "size" attributes value of items in the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

I want to display the color and size of the configurable product in the cart. I got all the details other than the color and size values. My code is

```
 `$itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

 foreach($itemsVisible as $item) {
    $id = $item->getProductId();
    $name = $item->getName();
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    $qty = $item->getQty();
    $price = $item->getPrice();
    $size = $item->getSize(); 
    $color =  $item->getColor();`
  }
```

color and size return blank. How can I get these values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following code to get attribute in cart page.

```
    $itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

     foreach($itemsVisible as $item) {
        $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        $id = $item->getProductId();
        $name = $item->getName();
        $sku = $item->getSku();
        $qty = $item->getQty();
        $price = $item->getPrice();
        // Following code for size and color. Use attribute code in place of size and color
        $size = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        $color =  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`
      }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hi Rohit, I got the value "No" for color and size. And when I change $itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems(); to    $itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems(); it will show all the items in configurable product other than the main item.

Comment: in `getAttribute()` function use your attribute code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 <?php
 $itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
 foreach($itemsVisible as $item) {
    $id = $item->getProductId();
    $name = $item->getName();
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    $qty = $item->getQty();
    $price = $item->getPrice();
 $_product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
  $_product->getSize();
  $_product->getColor();

}
```

Comment: Hi arunendra, It'll return the null value for me

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
 foreach($itemsVisible as $item) {
     $product = $item->getProduct();
     $attrs  = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
    foreach($attrs as $attr) {
        if(0 == strcmp("color", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
            $options    = $attr['values'];
            foreach($options as $option) {
                print "{$option['store_label']}<br />";
            }
        }
        if(0 == strcmp("size", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
            $options    = $attr['values'];
            foreach($options as $option) {
                print "{$option['store_label']}<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
$itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
 foreach($itemsVisible as $item) {
     $product = $item->getProduct();
     $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectedAttributesInfo($product);
     foreach($attributes as $attr) {
        if(0 == strcmp("color", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
            $options    = $attr['values'];
            foreach($options as $option) {
                print "{$option['store_label']}<br />";
            }
        }
        if(0 == strcmp("size", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
            $options    = $attr['values'];
            foreach($options as $option) {
                print "{$option['store_label']}<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```