# How to add multiple product to cart and get cart id in magento 1.9 for guest checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, programmatically, guest-checkout

I am trying to store multiple products to cart and getting cart id of the products list for generating order in Magento 1.9. I don't know how to create cart and order for guest checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code used for pragmatically create order in magento.

```
$productids=array(1,2,4,3);
 $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
 $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
 // Start New Sales Order Quote
 $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getId());

 // Set Sales Order Quote Currency
 $quote->setCurrency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode());

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');

$customer->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
         ->setStore($store)
         ->setFirstname($firstName)
         ->setLastname($lastName)
         ->setEmail($email);  


 // Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
 $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

     // Configure Notification
 $quote->setSendCconfirmation(1);
 foreach($productids as $id){
     $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
     $quote->addProduct($product,new Varien_Object(
 array(
   'qty'   => 1,
   'super_attribute' => [$sizeAttribute->getId() => $valueMedium, 
                 $colorAttribute->getId() => $valueGreen ]
   )
 ));
 }     
 // Set Sales Order Billing Address
 $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
     'customer_address_id' => '',
     'prefix' => '',
     'firstname' => 'john',
     'middlename' => '',
     'lastname' =>'Deo',
     'suffix' => '',
     'company' =>'', 
     'street' => array(
             '0' => 'Noida',
             '1' => 'Sector 64'
         ),
     'city' => 'Noida',
     'country_id' => 'IN',
     'region' => 'UP',
     'postcode' => '201301',
     'telephone' => '78676789',
     'fax' => 'gghlhu',
     'vat_id' => '',
     'save_in_address_book' => 1
 ));

 // Set Sales Order Shipping Address
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
     'customer_address_id' => '',
     'prefix' => '',
     'firstname' => 'john',
     'middlename' => '',
     'lastname' =>'Deo',
     'suffix' => '',
     'company' =>'', 
     'street' => array(
             '0' => 'Noida',
             '1' => 'Sector 64'
         ),
     'city' => 'Noida',
     'country_id' => 'IN',
     'region' => 'UP',
     'postcode' => '201301',
     'telephone' => '78676789',
     'fax' => 'gghlhu',
     'vat_id' => '',
     'save_in_address_book' => 1
 ));
 if($shipprice==0){
     $shipmethod='freeshipping_freeshipping';
 }

 // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
 $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                 ->collectShippingRates()
                 ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
                 ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

 // Set Sales Order Payment
 $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));

 // Collect Totals & Save Quote
 $quote->collectTotals()->save();

 // Create Order From Quote
 $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
 $service->submitAll();
 $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();

 // Resource Clean-Up
 $quote = $customer = $service = null;

 // Finished
 echo $increment_id;
```

Comment: In this code, you are passing products ids only, I want to store products with options(colour, size). It is possible to add products to cart with attribute options and get the cart id or quote id for processing a guest checkout. Here you are creating customer also. But for guest checkout, there is no need to create a customer account.

Comment: I have updated my code please check.

Comment: Thanks, I need one more clarification, how to create an order for configurable products. In your case **super_attribute** colour and size how to get the exact colour and size what we selected while adding the product to cart. I have a little confusion of configurable products order.

Comment: This link will may help you..https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104470/how-can-i-get-the-color-and-size-attributes-value-of-items-in-the-cart

Comment: I need one clarification inm custom block, Please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251916/how-to-create-custom-block-for-cart-page-in-magneto-1-9 Check this link.